# Android FlexBox-Layout Customize - Column Standard Limit

Tags: android, flexbox, android-flexboxlayout

I use [Flexbox-Layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). I want to restrict with the Column Standard Limit.

When the application was first loaded, I managed to run [the formula in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMCZe.png). [Default Activity Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrHF0.jpg).
However, when the filter runs, there is deterioration. [Deterioration screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBzlK.jpg)

I know it's wrong, but I've restricted it to maxWidth and maxHeight when I first load it (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams).

How do you think I can?

Comment: no answer on internet i am also finding solutions :)

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately . I solved my problem by added empty objects. I know it doesn't make sense. :(

Comment: if size is big so may be it's problem by the way thanks for your response ,this is feature google have to add it in flex layout